# Redirect in php Users from Hong Kong or Spain to another site

Tags: php, redirect, ip, country

I am trying to visiting my site to another sub site for visitors from Hong Kong or spain. I am trying to use the following code to redirect visitors based on IP, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
if($ipnum >= ip2long('2.20.179.0') && $ipnum <= ip2long('2.20.179.255')){
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/es/');
}
elseif($ipnum >= ip2long('14.0.128.0') && $ipnum <= ip2long('14.0.255.255')){
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/hk/');
}
```

Kindly help with corrections or modifications.

Comment: Have you tried [GeoIP with PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) ?

Comment: It's a shared hosting. We can't install the extension required to run GeoIP.

Comment: ok, then have you tried to add "return" in front of header ?

Comment: Can ou share some code on what you mean?

Comment: instead of `header('Location: http://www.example.com/es/');` make `return header('Location: http://www.example.com/es/');`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using 3rd party API which responses you the country of visitor.

Try using this API :

http://www.telize.com/geoip/2.20.179.0 (http://www.telize.com/)

And add your redirection conditions based on response of this API.